# Ruby on Rails: Google is not defined after render :new

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, geocomplete

I'm using geocomplete to enter an address field of a `#create` form. Google map apis are loaded in the head.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<%= ENV['DEV_MAPS_API_KEY'] %>&libraries=places">  </script>
</head>
```

Application.js.erb

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#gig_location").geocomplete();
});
```

This works fine on page load, and if I refresh the page I don't have any problems either.

Problems arise if there are form errors. I am using `render :new` so inputted form fields are not lost, but as the page reloads I get the `Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined` error message.

Gig_controller.rb

```
  def create 
      .....code....
    if @gig.save
      redirect_to @gig
      flash[:success] = "Gig created successfully"
    else
      @errors = @gig.errors
      @gig = Gig.new(gig_params.merge(genres: genres))
      render :new
    end
   end
```

If I user `redirect_to new_gig_path` this reloads everything and `geocomplete` works, but form inputs are wiped also.

Other jquery elements keep working after `render :new` is called, it's only google map apis that don't.

How can I reload/save the google map api jquery upon rendering `:new`?

Comment: have you tried `$(window).on('load', function() { 'code'})` instead of `$(document).ready`?

Comment: This doesn't work either, I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

add below code to your new.html.erb:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#gig_location").geocomplete();
})
```

Comment: This does not work for me. It gives me the same ´google not defined´ error, but twice.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured this out. 
`render :new` is actually calling the `create [POST]` action, not `new`.

My google map apis are loaded conditionally depending on the controller and action. Adding them to the `gig#create` action (not just `gig#new`) allows them to be loaded when `render :new` is called.

Maybe this will help someone that is having difficulties when using `render :new`.